# fuzzyfinder: Error detected while processing function <SNR>19_onCommandPre

Tags: vim, fuzzyfinder

When typing an command, I get an error like this:

```
:w
Error detected while processing function <SNR>19_onCommandPre..fuf#mrucmd#onCommandPre..<SNR>25_updateInfo..fuf#updateMruList:
line    2:
E121: Undefined variable: word
line    5:
E121: Undefined variable: word
```

Is it a bug or just cause by my incorrect configuration?

I set `let g:fuf_modesDisable=[]` in my .vimrc.

And the vim version I use if vim 7.3, the fuzzyfinder version is fuzzyfinder 4.2.2

Comment: The Bitbucket project for FuzzyFinder no longer exists in 2022, so the link in the accepted answer is a 404, but the suggestion of looking inside `~/.vim-fuf-data/mrufile/items` for an obviously-corrupted entry (or deleting the file) should work for anyone arriving here in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same (or very similar) problem. I've filed [issues](https://bitbucket.org/ns9tks/vim-fuzzyfinder/issue/64/error-detected-while-processing-function) against FuzzyFinder.

If you follow the link you will find the details of my investigation together with solution.
If nothing else work I believe that wiping out `~/.vim-fuf-data` directory will do. But better to try what is described in the issue first (`~/.vim-fuf-data/mrufile/items`).

Comment: Yeah, just `rm ~/.vim-fuf-data/mrufile/items` worked for me. Thanks a million!

Comment: Or—because this happened to me again, later—just edit `~/.vim-fuf-data/mrufile/items` by hand and look for obvious corruption in the file. In this second instance, it was obvious the last line of the file was truncated, so I just deleted that line and bam!, back in business.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. Deleting the FuzzyFinder data file fixed the issue for me. Of course I am starting from scratch now, but it works!

Delete the following:

```
~/.vimfuzzyfinder
```

Answer (score 0):

Just doing a plugin install seemed to fix the issue for me